# JScript Escape an ampersand in payload data for URL

Tags: jscript

I am attempting to launch a view using the following JS function:

```
    $('#filterTop').click(function () {
        var filterValue = $('#filterValueTop').val();
        refreshView(`@Url.Action(Model.Action, Model.Controller)?pageSize=@Model.PageSize&pageNumber=@Model.PageNumber&sortDesc=@Model.SortDescending&filterType=@Model.FilterType&filterValue=${filterValue}&showAll=@Model.ShowAll` + `@Model.Payload`, '@Model.ResultView');
    });
```

It worked great until I needed to append a static payload to the end of the URL. The relevant part is line 3 at the end:

```
&showAll=@Model.ShowAll` + `@Model.Payload`
```

I am assigning @Model.Payload a value of:

```
opts.Payload = "&batchID=" + batchID;
```

or "&batchID=25". The resulting URL is:

```
https://localhost:44303/Employee/Repaginate?pageSize=20&pageNumber=1&sortDesc=True&filterType=Name&filterValue=Jes&showAll=False&amp;batchID=25
```

For some reason, it's translating the "&" to "&a.m.p;" (with no periods) which isn't a valid URL. I've tried various methods of escaping the character like using "%26", "/&", and several other garden varieties but alas, my attempts have been in vain. Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What even is this?  This doesn't look like any JScript I'm familiar with.  The first code block strongly resembles jquery, then there are several `@object.property` tokens referenced.  Are those referencing some sort of precompile declaration?  I'm not accustomed to seeing Microsoft Windows Script Host JScript variables named that way.  If this is supposed to be a jquery question, please edit your tags appropriately.

Comment: It's a JScript query I use to submit a URL to an AJAX request to refresh views in my MVC project. The #Model. tokens are part of my ViewModel that is sent to an MVC view. The #Model parts render first leaving behind the values for the query, then when the submit button is clicked, I simply harvest the filterValue (input text from the user) and ship it off to another function to perform the necessary update and redisplay of the page.